# echo/printf redirection not working in background process

Tags: io-redirection, background-process, echo

I've a command like this:

```
sudo sh -c "echo $ADDR > /sys/class/gpio/export"
```

It runs properly from the shell, but if I run it as a background process I get the following error:

> no tty present and no askpass program specified

How could I solve this problem?

Thank you

**Edit** I forgot to show you the steps I have done:

1. Connected to my embedded linux by SSH.
2. Run a script which contains the above command by "nohup  &".
3. Now the process is running in background.
4. The LEDs attached to the GPIO board work as expected.
5. I disconnect the SSH session.
6. The LEDs do not work anymore.
7. I connect again by SSH and into the file *nohup.out* I read "**no tty present and no askpass program specified**".

Comment: Why do you need to run it in the background?

Comment: I need it, for some reasons, why this question?!

Comment: Why my question has been down voted!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the issue is that you're backgrounding the entire `sudo` process, and it's unable to prompt you for the password.

You could:

- `sudo` run something else and give it the password, followed by your command (depending on your sudo configuration) or
- configure sudo (via `visudo`) to allow your user/group to run sudo commands without a password: `%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

The second is a much more sensible solution, though there are obviously many more solutions, but it would help a lot if you explained your primary need.

Comment: Hi, I think you are right. As soon as possibile I will try and I will give you a feedback. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are better off putting your parameters in /etc/sysfs.conf

See

https://serverfault.com/questions/373624/suggestions-for-making-sysfs-parameters-persist-across-reboots